# ¿Para enviar una imagen a un webservices debo codificarla a Base64?

Tags: java, android, webservice

Quisiera saber si para enviar la imagen desde java debo primero codificarla.

Comment: *No* necesariamente. ¿Por qué no agregas código de la parte relevante?

Comment: @PaulVargas No tengo código, solo quiero saber como es la manera mas conveniente de enviar la imagen al server, para luego si implementarlo

Comment: @JDeveloper Todo depende de tus necesidades...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Me parece que te refieres a como enviar el arreglo de bytes de una imagen en un Web Service, para enviarlo, teniendo el arreglo de bytes, como mencionas tienes que codificarlo a `Base64` de esta forma:

```
String miImagen = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

`miImagen` sería el valor que enviarías en el WebService.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar MTOM (desde Java 6) [JAX-WS MTOM](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-attachment-with-mtom/), o como string en base 64, como dice Elenasys.