# ¿Puedo usar datos tipo blob con Bundle en Android?

Tags: android, mysql, eclipse

Tengo que subir imágenes a una base de datos (con `blob`), pero esta recibe los datos desde `Bundle`, he probado varias cosas y me da error por el tipo de archivo que intento subir y me gustaría saber si se puede o no usar  `Bundle` de esta manera.

El código que usa `Bundle` es este (el código no es mío, no sé muy bien como funciona):

```
Bundle datos = new Bundle();
datos.putString("NombreCampo", CampoBD);
datos.putString("NombreCampo", CampoBD);
...
```

Me gustaría saber si en ese `datos.putString()` puedo poner un blob

Comment: De que manera utilizas el Bundle?

Comment: Edité el post, espero que sea más aclaratorio.

Comment: En el objeto Bundle es donde quieres almacenar la imagen (o imágenes) para mandarla a la base de datos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo de la manera que indicas, pero preferentemente debes [codificarla a base 64](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18296/para-enviar-una-imagen-a-un-webservices-debo-codificarla-a-base64/18332#18332):

```
String imagenCodificada = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

---

**Personalmente para evitar problemas de memoria o datos corruptos, prefiero enviar en el `Intent` el url de la imagen, o incluso guardar en base de datos la url.**

Comment: Yo también pero es lo que me piden en mi empresa.

Answer (score 1):

Con putString podes poner un String.

Si tenés datos binarios, podés codificarlos como base64 para tener una representación como string al costo de incrementar el número de bytes.

Si los guardas en la base de datos de esta forma no será un blob sino un string muy largo.

También podés decodificar el base64 a binario antes de hacer el insert en la base de datos, en ese caso el dato lo guardas como blob y el incremento en el tamaño sería solo para poder mandarlo de un Fragment a otro en el Bundle (Si es que para eso se usa este Bundle en particular).